# SQL Replication using Two Availability Group

Tags: sql-server, replication, availability-groups

Is it possible to setup SQL Replication with Two Availability Group Cluster? one is Publisher(or Distributor if not in different server) and the other AG is Subscriber?

Answer (score 1):

Sure. [The docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/replication-subscribers-and-always-on-availability-groups-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) have plenty of detail on how, and specific details that might affect your implementation.

I'd recommend configuring your distributor as a third, dedicated AG (assuming 2017+).

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your version of SQL Server.

From SQL Server 2012 to SQL Server 2017 CU5, you can't setup AG for distributor database.

Starting [SQL Server 2017 CU6 and on SQL Server 2016 SP2-CU3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/configure-distribution-availability-group?view=sql-server-ver15), you can setup AG for distributor database and it is required you have a remote distributor. This is only supported for Transactional Replication. If you have merge, bi-directional replication, P2P, it is not supported.

Here's a [good walkthrough on how to setup the Publisher, Distribution, and Subscriber in AG](https://repltalk.com/2019/03/09/walkthrough-publisher-distributor-subscriber-in-alwayson-availability-groups/).